# Make my oracle apex application point to website home page url

Tags: http, oracle-apex, oracleapplications

I have my oracle apex database application built in a oracle web hosting server. For ex, it is like http://www.myapexhostingserver.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1:13225322000472

Here I have created many apex database applications. Now I have specific domains for each of these apex applications. Currently, I have written a redirect in each of these domain settings to my apex application. 
For ex,

```
http://www.domain1.com has a redirect url set to http://myapexhostingserver.com/pls/apex/f?p=162:LOGIN:16888048444232

http://www.domain2.com has a redirect url set to http://myapexhostingserver.com/pls/apex/f?p=165:LOGIN:16888048444232
```

A redirect is not google friendly. But I cannot purchase oracle web hosting for each domain too. Is there any other good solution available?

Meaning, when I buy a shared hosting server, I can create as many PHP applications I want. But not sure if this is also possible in oracle apex.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Developing Oracle Apex Applications with Search Engine Visible Designs

*This is a discussion on the issues with the varying style of APEX Application url syntax. There also is an explanation of how APEX work space namespaces are organized to show how application url's can be customized using a single database instance.*

> **Comments:**  Some Internet searches can yield an answer that you're looking for.  There are a number of developers and consulting gigs out there who have tackled the problem of converting between the popular, canonical url paths and the notation used by Oracle APEX.

Some search terms that proved useful include: `oracle apex pretty url`, `url mapping`, and `http url mapping plsql`.  The most useful guides were examples in Oracle PL/SQL, but you can also dive deeper and set up rules on the web server engine (i.e., Apache HTTP Server) that re-interprets URL requests so that the APEX styled addresses are masked.  This isn't necessary, but some techniques such as "url remapping" are among the possible solutions.

What this post is **NOT** is a guide on specifics of Search Engine Optimization (SEO), which may be distantly related to the OP's question about "Google Friendliness", but is beyond the scope of this solution guide.

### Are Oracle APEX Websites Search Engine Friendly?

A comment quoted directly from the original post was worth researching and addressing.  This is mostly an incorrect conclusion.

> A redirect is not google friendly.

This actually depends on how you set things up on your APEX website.  Redirects are one way of managing incoming traffic that use alternate url naming schemes, but this is not the only approach.

**Some Successful Blogs and Websites Done in Apex:**

Some online groups such as the APEX developer team with [APEX Ninjas](http://www.apexninjas.com/blog/) continue to report growing referrals from search engines such as *Google* without many changes to the way their Oracle APEX powered site and blog.

Another good example is the active APEX website:  **"ASK Tom"**, which was created by Oracle's Tom Kyte.  This site has run on APEX for many years now and references to pages on this website continue to appear on search engine result pages the familiar APEX style url formatting from the "ASK Tom" website.

### Using Better Navigation URLs for Clarity

Web server `REDIRECTS` are one approach to mapping cleaner url address syntax on top of an Oracle Apex Listener.  We use the [Abyss Web Server Engine](http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/), which is a light-weight http server that sits on the front of our company APEX application server. It's not absolutely necessary, but we chose it for its simplified management of a singlular web server task.  Redirects work fine for us as well.  Though we have not explored further, advanced features such as `virtual hosting` and `url rewriting rules` may take you further regarding your requirement to separate out multiple TLDs (primary domains) or C-NAMEs (sub-domains) on the same Apex listener instance.

The ugliest of the URL forms in APEX Applications is the default.  It is decipherable, but not friendly to the human eye or simple enough to remember.  Here is an example shot of the URL assigned to the `HOME` page of my application named: `APEX-LAB-PUB`

[image: Default Oracle APEX Application and Page Identification]

This is a common format of the URLs that an Oracle APEX web server will interpret.  So the general format to observe is that everything after the clause:  **f?p=...**

```
http://somedomain.com/pls/apex/f?p=1312786:5:987529480
```

By using the alternative option of setting `ALIAS` names, you can create short-cut url forms in the same layout, but with human readable alias assignments:

[image: Aliased Oracle APEX Application and Page Identification]

This is good, but there is also a common practice which uses Oracle Apex's native REST Web Service listener so that internal and external links look simpler.  Simplified url syntax can also make setting up redirect hooks cleaner and more organized.

### Oraganizing APEX Application Websites Using REST Web Services

To develop this example, I used [Oracle's free Apex hosting](http://apex.oracle.com) tier. Although it has some limitations on what features are available, RESTful web services are enabled on the Apex listener of this platform, which is what we need.

**Mapping a Web Service URI to an Apex URL Request**

This is the url syntax we will be using will look something like this:

```
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/...(workspace)/...(uri request)
```

**Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)**

This is the part that will be appended to the end of the base url of the Oracle Apex hosting listener.  The example below is just a generic template:

```
Generic URI Syntax                       This Solution URI

hr/employees/{ID}                        display/{app}/{page}
|_|_________|____|                       |______|____________|
 |     |      |                              |        |
 |     |       -Handler Bind Variable        |         -Handler Bind Variable(s)
 |     |                                     | 
 |      - URI Template                        - URI Template
 |
  - Module URI Prefix


-- RESTful Service Design Summary

Module Name:           superEasyURL
URI Prefix (optional): (none)
URI Template:          display/{app}/{page}
Handler Method:        GET
Handler Source Type:   PL/SQL

Handler Source:

declare
   url varchar2(500);
   baseurl constant  varchar2(2000):= 
        'https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=';

begin
   url:= baseurl || :app || ':' || :page;

   :URL := url;
   :STATUS := 303;

end;
```

**Note:** You will also need to set two `OUT` parameters for this REST Service to represent the two bind variables in the above PL/SQL statement for the values of `URL` and `STATUS`:

[image: superEasyURL REST Service OUT Parameters]

**About the HTTP 303 Status Header Code**

There is another kind of HTTP status code called an [HTTP 303](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303).  You can use APEX to deliver pages and content that are *not* redirects.  Oracle Application Express and its RESTful Web services can receive traditional url requests that convert to the APEX format on the back-end.

**303 See Other** has been proposed as one way of responding to a request for a URI that identifies a real-world object according to Semantic Web theory (the other being the use of hash URIs).

> *For example*, if http://www.example.com/id/alice identifies a person, Alice, then it would be inappropriate for a server to respond to a GET request with `200 OK`, as the server could not deliver Alice herself. Instead the server would issue a 303 See Other response which redirected to a separate URI providing a description of the person Alice.
>
> [Reference Excerpt: Wikipedia.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303)

### Demonstration of a Working Example

This is an example created in my personal, Oracle hosted workspace.  This is the url which will be interpreted by the REST Service built earlier.

```
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/rgpascual/display/{app}/{page}
                                |_________|
                                     |
                                     |
                - Workspace ID String (required by the listener) -
```

Note that on the shared instance, an additional reference to the user's workspace name was required to make this translation happen.  I am not 100% sure if it is required, but I was able to complete this demo by using it in the final path references.

[image: Simple URL Path Before Service Translation]

Display of: `HOME` page (aliased) from the APEX-LAB-PUB Application (aliased as: `APEXLABPUB01`).

[image: Output Call to an Existing App and Page Alias]

### Conclusions, Questions and General Advice

The efforts of this post offers the possibility of using pretty url syntax to represent navigation links within an Apex Application website.  Instead of the default notation defined by Oracle, a navigation link list may look like:

**Note**: These links *do not work*.  They are just to illustrate the advantages of this presented solution.

> - **Home**
>
>   Actual Requested URL:
>      someapexserver.../pls/apex/mywork/display/new-app/home
> - **About Us**
>
>   Actual Requested URL:
>      someapexserver.../pls/apex/mywork/display/new-app/about
> - **Contact**
>
>   Actual Requested URL:
>      someapexserver.../pls/apex/mywork/display/new-app/contactus
> - **Associates**
>
>   Actual Requested URL:
>      someapexserver.../pls/apex/mywork/display/new-app/associates
> - **Business Ops**
>
>   Actual Requested URL:
>      someapexserver.../pls/apex/mywork/display/new-app/businessops

Now, referring links and navigation is uniform and consistent using the URI template chosen in the initial design of this solution.

**Additional Questions:  Application Capacity of a Single Apex Instance**

There was an additional question about the way that Oracle Apex manages applications created in a single instance.

> ... Meaning, when I buy a shared hosting server, I can create as many PHP applications I want. But not sure if this is also possible in oracle apex.

You should consider reviewing the Apex documentation put out by Oracle to understand how the Apex security framework affects the possibilities or organizing multiple applications created from the same database instance.

[image: Oracle APEX Login Screen]

A few things to note however:

- A single database installation, or `INSTANCE` can contain multiple divisions called `WORKSPACES`.  Workspaces by default cannot see what is in other workspaces but applications within may share access to the same database schemas on the back-end.
- A `WORKSPACE` may contain any number of APEX applications.  Each application enabled with login security may have its own user authentication or it may use the "native" authentication process.  Without further configuration,  Application User accounts in the same Workspace will have have access to the other apps in the same workspace.
- The `USER NAMESPACES` of each Workspace are separate, i.e. there may be two user accounts with the same name between two or more different Workspaces. (a user named `ADMIN` in both WORKSPACE1 and WORKSPACE2 are NOT the same user.)
- `NAMED DATABASE USERS` may have access across other multiple Apex workspaces.  A user defined this way is unique across every workspace and application permitting its access.  Access users defined as Named Database Users are defined unique across a given database `INSTANCE`.

So in conclusion, Apex is designed to support multiple applications similarly to hosting on a single, shared hosting set up.  Chances are however, if you are looking for the amount of control you describe in the OP, your shared hosting will most likely be your own `Dedicated Server` solution,  `VPS` (Virtual Private Server) or `AWS` (Amazon Web Services) host.

You will need a host with enough access to server resources to:  (a) Permit the installation of Oracle database software on the host. (b) Allow the configuration (opening and/or closing) of server networking ports. (c) Enough server resources to support the active operation of the installed database instance and the web-requests serviced by the accompanying HTTP based listener.

If you want your installation to manage multiple moderately sized and trafficked web applications, you will need a lot more than the minimum server specifications described in the installation instructions of the Oracle database version and edition you choose.